# Is it possible to override OmxPlayer's volume in RetroPie/EmulationStation?

Tags: retropie, alsa, emulation

I have my RetroPie EmulationStation set up to be 40% volume which makes for some good game volumes on my Picade's speaker. However, for the game snaps, I cannot hear the audio at all.

When I look at the parameters based to omxplayer using `ps -fp <pid of omxplayer.bin>`, I can see it's passing values like **"-4000"** for **"--vol"**, which is just too quiet (experimenting and **"-1000"** sounds about right and equivalent to the in-game volume generated by the 40% setting)

If I push the main volume up to 75%, omxplayer is fine but then the game volume is far too loud.

Does anyone know how I can override the values being passed to omxplayer.bin independently of the main game volume EmulationStation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, no sooner do I ask this question than I come across a solution that works.

1. By settings the EmulationStation volume to 75% (so snaps play well)
2. Modify `/opt/retropie/configs/all/runcommand-onstart.sh` to have the line `amixer set PCM 40%`
3. Modify `/opt/retropie/configs/all/runcommand-onend.sh` to have the line `amixer set PCM 75%`

Ideally wouldn't need to do this though. Maybe there is something I'm missing?